# SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build() deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm using Exoplayer in my app and initializing exoplayer as

```
player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
```

But Android Studio is giving me warning as it is deprecated. When I get to the lower version of Exoplayer `2.15.1`, then warning goes off. But in latest version `2.16.0`, it is giving deprecation warning. How can we initialize exoplayer now with the latest version?

Comment: As per the release notes for 2.16.0: Deprecate `SimpleExoPlayer`. All functionality has been moved to `ExoPlayer` instead. `ExoPlayer.Builder` can be used instead of `SimpleExoPlayer.Builder`. You can find further changes here https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/releases

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`SimpleExoPlayer` Deprecated. All functionality has been moved to `ExoPlayer` instead. `ExoPlayer.Builder` can be used instead of `SimpleExoPlayer.Builder`.

Initialize your exoplayer as

```
player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
```

You can check the changes done in library for version 2.16.0 in [release notes](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/RELEASENOTES.md)

Answer (score 7):

`SimpleExoPlayer` deprecated. You should use `ExoPlayer`

`implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.2'`

Example:

```
private var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer? = null
exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
```

Answer (score 4):

In `2.16.1` do as following.

```
ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
```

Pls see : https://exoplayer.dev/hello-world.html

Answer (score 2):

player intialization.

```
val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
    setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"))
}
```

and **PlayerView** is now replaced with **StyledPlayerView**

```
StyledPlayerView(context).apply {
            player = exoPlayer
            layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )

        }
```

Compose example below.

```
@Composable
fun VideoPlayer() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val exoPlayer = remember(context) {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
            setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"))
        }
    }

    DisposableEffect(key1 = exoPlayer) {
        onDispose {
            exoPlayer.release()
        }
    }

    AndroidView(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(214.dp), factory = {
        StyledPlayerView(context).apply {
            player = exoPlayer
            layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )

        }
    })
}
```